# Disabled "Filtered Parameter" drop-down in custom web part with connections

Tags: web-part, development, connected-web-parts

I'm writing a web part that needs to use connections for processing values relating to a business object called a "Program Entity". It is supposed to take in an ID provided by a connected web part, perform some processing, then spit out a 'token' for consumption by a different connected web part. The token is just the ID in another format.

I have the drop-down menu correctly displaying as follows:

```
Connections -> Send Program Entity Token To -> ...
            -> Get Program Entity ID From -> ...
```

When I select a web part in "Get Program Entity ID From", a dialog appears for me to choose a Filtered Parameter. However the dropdown of parameters is greyed out and just says "No Parameters". Note: the web part I'm trying to connect to is also custom and may not have been fully completed and tested for providing a value via a connection.

Is there anything that explains why I'm unable to set up a connection? Here is the code for my web part:

```
public class ProgramEntityTokenConverter : WebPart, ITransformableFilterValues
{
    public bool AllowAllValue
    {
     get { return true; }
    }

    public bool AllowEmptyValue
    {
     get { return false; }
    }

    public bool AllowMultipleValues
    {
     get { return false; }
    }

    public string ParameterName
    {
     get { return "ProgramEntityToken"; }
    }

    public ReadOnlyCollection<string> ParameterValues
    {
     get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(ConvertProgramEntityIDs()); }
    }

    [ConnectionProvider("Program Entity Token", "ProgramEntityToken", AllowsMultipleConnections = false)]
    public ITransformableFilterValues SetConnectionInterface()
    {
     return this;
    }

    private IList<string> ConvertProgramEntityIDs()
    {
     return null; // TODO
    }

    [ConnectionConsumer("Program Entity ID", "ProgramEntityID", AllowsMultipleConnections = false)]
    public void SetFilter(IFilterValues filterValues)
    {
     if (filterValues != null)
     {
      EnsureChildControls();
      List<ConsumerParameter> parameters = new List<ConsumerParameter>();
      parameters.Add(new ConsumerParameter("ProgramEntityID", ConsumerParameterCapabilities.SupportsSingleValue));
      filterValues.SetConsumerParameters(new ReadOnlyCollection<ConsumerParameter>(parameters));
     }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now fixed by changing this line:

```
parameters.Add(new ConsumerParameter("ProgramEntityID", 
    ConsumerParameterCapabilities.SupportsSingleValue));
```

to this line:

```
parameters.Add(new ConsumerParameter("ProgramEntityID", 
    ConsumerParameterCapabilities.SupportsSingleValue | 
    ConsumerParameterCapabilities.SupportsAllValue));
```

The web part I was trying to connect to had the `AllowAllValue` property set to true which was clearly excluded by `ConsumerParameterCapabilities`.

---

As an aside, I also tried:

```
parameters.Add(new ConsumerParameter("ProgramEntityID", 
    ConsumerParameterCapabilities.SupportsMultipleValues | 
    ConsumerParameterCapabilities.SupportsAllValue));
```

... however the web part I'm connecting to has `AllowMultipleValues` set to false! It seems odd that `ConsumerParameterCapabilities` enforces possible connections according to `AllowAllValue` but `AllowMultipleValues` does not.

Comment: Isn't answering you own question a little like lobbing a basketball to yourself for a dunk? I'll admit, I asked one question hear, blogged the answer and then found someone had gotten answer credit for linking to my blog post.

Comment: Adding  an answer to your own Q gives you minimal (if any) credits, unless ofcourse you get upvoted because you did a good job :-) Both Q and A are good examples on how to ask and answer a question, and definately adds value to this site